# azurepipelines template task condition not evaluating as expected

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

When I remove the task condition from the deploy_data_factory_steps.yaml template the parameter displays with the expected value:

```
parameter is DEV2
```

But when I run with the condition it fails to evaluate as True:

```
Evaluating: and(succeeded(), eq('$(env)', 'DEV2'))
Expanded: and(True, eq('$(env)', 'DEV2'))
Result: False
```

azurepipelines.yaml:

```
- stage: DataFactoryDEV2
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.runEnv }}', 'dev2'))
  dependsOn: DeployDEV2
  variables:
    - group: xxx_DEV2
  pool: 
    name: 'yyyDev'
  jobs: 
  - deployment: deploy
    environment: xxx-dev2
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - template: templates/deploy_data_factory_steps.yml
            parameters:
              environ: $(env)
              artifact: 'publish-factory'
              azureSubscription: 'yyy - xxx'
```

deploy_data_factory_steps.yaml

```
steps:
...

- task: AzureCLI@2
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.environ }}', 'DEV2'))
  displayName: 'Blah blah blah'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    scriptType: bash
    inlineScript: |
      echo parameter is ${{ parameters.environ }}
```

Comment: Where does `$(env)` come from, how is it defined. Try using `${{ variables.env }}` instead to make sure the value is passed at template expansion time instead if runtime.

Comment: Some values aren't yet available when templates are expanded and conditions are evaluated. In which case their verbatim name is passed in. Looks like you're hitting this case.

Comment: And in your condition you don't need to use ${{}}, you can reperence parameters with `parameters.name` and variables with `variables.name` or `variables['name']` without enclosing them in ${{} while you're in the expression syndax

Comment: @jessehouwing $(env) is a variable which exists inside the variable group xxx_DEV2. I have updated the original post to show this

Comment: It didn't seem to work with ${{ variables.env }}.